# Confuse about css bfc(Block formatting contexts)

Tags: css, block

In w3c the BFC is defined as this:

> In a block formatting context, **boxes** are laid out one after the other, vertically, beginning at the top of a containing block. The vertical distance between two sibling boxes is determined by the 'margin' properties. Vertical margins between adjacent block-level boxes in a block formatting context collapse.
>
> In a block formatting context, each **box's** left outer edge touches the left edge of the containing block (for right-to-left formatting, right edges touch). This is true even in the presence of floats (although a box's line boxes may shrink due to the floats), unless the box establishes a new block formatting context (in which case the box itself may become narrower due to the floats).

I don't quite understand the meaning of `boxes`, is this means `display:block` element?

If it is means the `block` element, what about the `inline` element or the `float` element?I didn't see any description about other kinds of element, how to deal with other elements?

What's the block element representation differences in normal flow and BFC? I think they the same, just one next to the other vertically from left top to bottom

Answer (score 2):

UA generate rectangular boxes for elements in the document tree.

see[Controlling box generation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#box-gen)

and about block element in BFC:

> box's left outer edge touches the left edge of the containing block (for right-to-left formatting, right edges touch). This is true even in the presence of floats

example:

```
<div>
    <div style="float:left;height:29px;background-color:yellow;">aaaaaa</div>
    <div style="background-color:gray;height:50px;"><b>ddddd</b></div>
</div>
```

vs

```
<div>
    <div style="float:left;height:29px;background-color:yellow;">aaaaaa</div>
    <div style="background-color:gray;height:50px;overflow:hidden;"><b>ddddd</b></div>
</div>
```